# Use fs.watch to watch mutiple files in different directory and come across some error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use fs.watch to watch mutiple files in different directory,(I use Mac)

```
fs.watch(file1, { recursive: false },(event, filename) => {
  console.log(`event ${event} filename =${filename}`)
})

fs.watch(file2, { recursive: false },(event, filename) => {
  console.log(`event ${event} filename =${filename}`)
})

fs.watch(file3, { recursive: false },(event, filename) => {
  console.log(`event ${event} filename =${filename}`)
})
```

and when I open may Mac Finder and focus anyone of the watched files, the change event will be invoke.

When I just watch only one file, the fs.watch works properly, i will only receive change event while I exactly modify the file content.

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you edit the question to make it more understandable.?

Comment: fs.watch uses chokidar under the hood. And it has some reported problems on mac. e.g : https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/issues/166